# Will petroleum jelly degrade silicone elastomer?

Tags: materials, chemical-engineering, material-science

I have gotten conflicting information on this question. If I put a bit (1/4 of a cc) of vaseline on a silicone elastomer part and then apply gentle pressure for hours will this degrade the elastomer? The answers I have so far: two no, one yes. One of the nos was from the manufacturer of the elastomer part so I think that's good enough but it seems prudent to check with the experts.

Sources would be helpful.

Feel free to edit the tags, I don't work in this space so I don't know the appropriate tags.

Comment: It effects a change, but whether that change counts as degradation to you is another story. For example, silicone earplugs are supposed to be broken in with Vaseline because it softens the silicone.

Comment: Also, just in case it didn't occur to you, your vague but verbose description of the part gives the impression that your question is about a sex toy, because if this was any other application you would just use the obvious thing: silicone grease.

Comment: This is not about a sex toy. This is about a medical device. I'd prefer not to describe it further because that's private information that isn't relevant to answering the question.

Comment: @DKNguyen - on the contrary, silicone grease is the one sure thing not to use. Like dissolves like.

Comment: @jcollum - For elastomer compatibility, my procedure is pretty much to hunt the web for material compatibility tables. Vaseline might need to be considered as a mixture of its principal ingredients, whatever they are. "petroleum jelly" is probably not specific enough. Temperature can make a difference, if that's applicable.

Comment: @PeteW Oh that does make sense. I was mistaken then. Heh.

Comment: @DKNguyen - PS, I've seen what happens, at least to a silicone an o-ring. it's not that dramatic, slight cracking after smth like a year

Comment: @PeteW That's much better than butyl rubber. I had a pair of expensive gloves melt into themselves within an hour.